# In Visual Studio Dark Theme how to get rid of white rectangle surrounding active line of code?

Tags: visual-studio, themes

[screenshot of rectangle in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hssaX.png)

In Visual Studio Dark theme there is a white rectangle surrounding the active line of code in the editor. This rectangle kind of ruins the clean black background and popping text. The settings under Tools>Options>... seem to be able to change the text forecolor/background color only and not the rectangle itslef. Anyone knows how to solve this? Also VS Code doesn't have this quirk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Text Editor** options you can uncheck **Highlight current line**.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks. While at it was able to uncheck the "Show Structure Guidelines" as well. The ambience is much better now.

Answer (score 0):

Open `settings.json` file and add this line:

`"editor.renderLineHighlight": "none"`